# 'vcxproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.vcxproj) is not supported

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am getting this error when a open a VS2010 sln file in the same version of 
Visual Studio (VS2010).

I installed all windows updates and service packs in hope to resolve the issue but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried various things but ultimately the problem was that I had installed only C# in Visual Studio 2010 and I had to go back and install C++ as well. That fixed the issue.

I did try [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenss/2009/09/25/problems-opening-your-project-files-in-visual-studio/) but it didn't work for me (run `devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs` on VS2010 command line).

Here is another [reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52bc04f9-f086-4adf-ac17-b0ea9f433c39/vbproj-is-not-supported-by-this-version-of-visual-studio?forum=vbide) which I tried but didn't work for me (it adds `devenv /setup` to the above).